# Haskell loop through a custom type

Tags: haskell

If I have the following custom type:

```
type MyType = String -> Bool
single :: Char -> MyType
concat :: MyType -> MyType -> MyType
```

and:

```
var :: MyType
var = concat (concat (single 'A') (single 'B')) (single 'C')
```

Is it possible to loop through var and see how many times concat and single are called?

Comment: `var` is a function, how would you propose you "loop through" a function?  Are you wanting to inspect the function's definition?  Code reflection isn't really the norm in Haskell and isn't particularly easy.  However, you could write a `data MyType` with fields representing the number of times `concat` and `single` are called, then in the definitions of those two functions just increment the respective field by 1.

Comment: Alternatively you could make an ADT to represent the structure, interpreting it later: `data Expr = Lit MyType | Concat Expr Expr | Single Char`.  Then you can inspect the structure to count the number of times `Concat` is used.

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks for the comment. I know using ADT works, as I have tried it. I am just wondering a similar trick can be applied if I use a custom type instead.

Comment: You can't do it with `type MyType = String -> Bool`.  There just aren't really ways to inspect a function's definition.  Your type and your functions have to handle this action explicitly.

Comment: i wonder if you might enjoy a logic language. Haskell is only good at solving a very limited class of equations—it pretty much expects you to tell it how to do its job, aside from some of the crazier type system shenanigans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not.

`var` has the type `MyType = String -> Bool`, so it is a function. The only thing you can do with a function is to call it. Calling `var` will either result in `true` or `false` because its result type is `Bool`. So that is not enough to encode the information you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If this cannot be done, how can I possibly achieved what I want as described in the EDIT?

Comment: @xcoder that's easy. Make a function that makes a string from that, like this: `toStr :: MyType -> String; toStr (Single a) = [a]; toStr (Concat a b) = toStr a ++ toStr b`. Then just compare the string with it!